# Why no <string.h> in getopt library?

Tags: c, windows, gnu, portability, getopt

I have been using Ludvig Jerabek's port of the GNU getopt on Windows and getting errors on lines like:

```
if (d->optind != argc && !_tcscmp(argv[d->optind], _T("--")))
```

`_tcscmp` is a macro that resolves to `strcmp` on my system and then it reports `strcmp` not found. If we examine the headers in getopt.cpp:

```
/* Getopt for Microsoft C  
....
Date: 02/03/2011 - Ludvik Jerabek - Initial Release
....
Revisions:
....
08/09/2011
....
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "getopt.h"
```

We see the problem: `<string.h>` is not included. I guess in Visual Studio `<string.h>` is included automatically maybe? I know I have successfully built getopt.cpp in Visual Studio, but using a manual environment with gcc on MinGW it is complaining about all the string compare functions being missing. What is the explanation for this?

Comment: try including it manually in the `getopt.cpp` and do a rebuilt..

Comment: @haris I know I can build the file that way. That is not the question. The question is why is string.h not included in getopt.cpp and how is that it does compile without error in visual studio.

Comment: What includes are in the `"getopt.h"` header?

Comment: @BenVoigt  only #include <tchar.h>

Comment: Well, that's where `_T` and `_tcscmp` should be.  Looks like your MinGW has a broken implementation of `<tchar.h>`

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't think tchar.h includes string.h. A header comment in tchar.h reads quote " /** Note that you still need to include string.h or stdlib.h etc. to define the appropriate functions. */"

Comment: @TylerDurden: The real one does `#include <string.h>` (depending on `UNICODE`), and does not contain any such comment.  Since Microsoft dreamt up `<tchar.h>` it is up to other compilers to conform to Microsoft's documentation.

Comment: Note that the `tchar.h` provided by the MinGW-w64 project does follow Microsoft's behavior of including `string.h` (or whichever is appropriate due to the UNICODE configuration). The TDM and nuwen MinGW distributions are now based on MinGW-w64 I believe. For whatever it's worth, those are the two MinGW distros that I use.

Answer (score 2):

The real `tchar.h` causes either `#include <string.h>` or `#include <mbstring.h>` depending on the character-set macros.

You have a broken version of `tchar.h` that does not correctly emulate these Microsoft-specific "Generic-Text Routine Mappings".

Comment: Hmm, it does seem that MinGW's version of tchar.h does not include <string.h>, so I guess the question would be why not.